# Javascript wont start script on load

Tags: javascript, html

I have a problem with my script no starting on load. It worked just yesterday but i changed my code to be more compact and now it isn't working. Before this mistake it worked fine without using `onload` in `body`.
Before the change it would show the current and next 6 days on the `li` elements but now it's just a blank box.

```js
function setweek() {
  var days["Sunday", "Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday", "Saturday", "Sunday", "Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday", "Saturday"]
  var elemen["first", "second", "third", "fourth", "fifth", "sixth", "seventh"]
  var day;
  var dayofmonth = 0;
  var plannedweek = 0;
  var d = new Date();
  var month = d.getMonth();
  for (var i = 0; i < 7; i++) {
    day = days[d.getDay() + i];
    dayofmonth = d.getDate() + i;
    check(i);
    document.getElementById(elemen[i]).innerHTML = day + '<br>' + dayofmonth + "." + month;
  }
}

function check(a) {
  var max = 31;
  if (d.getMonth() + l == 1) {
    max = 28;
  }
  if (d.getMonth() + l == 3) {
    max = 30;
  }
  if (d.getMonth() + l == 5) {
    max = 30;
  }
  if (d.getMonth() + l == 8) {
    max = 30;
  }
  if (d.getMonth() + l == 10) {
    max = 30;
  }
  if (d.getDate() + (a + (plannedweek * 7)) > max) {
    plannedweek = 0;
    month++;
    if (d.getMonth() + month > 12) {
      month = 0;
    }
  }
}
```

```html
<body onload="setweek();">
  <section id="meal_plan_section">
    <label for="weekly_meal_plan">Weekly meal plan:</label><br>
    <ul class="list-group" id="weekly_meal_plan">
      <li id="first" class="list-group-item list-group-item-action"></li>
      <li id="second" class="list-group-item list-group-item-action"></li>
      <li id="third" class="list-group-item list-group-item-action"></li>
      <li id="fourth" class="list-group-item list-group-item-action"></li>
      <li id="fifth" class="list-group-item list-group-item-action"></li>
      <li id="sixth" class="list-group-item list-group-item-action"></li>
      <li id="seventh" class="list-group-item list-group-item-action"></li>
    </ul>
  </section>
</body>
```

Comment: what was that ' change ' ? :)

Comment: you are missing `=` on these lines `var days` and `var elem`

Comment: compact dos not mean "readable". just separate the html structure from your scripts

Comment: @MihaiT Made it more compact with a for statement.

Comment: @rags2riches i have it separeted i just wrote it here connected so i wouldnt write the whole file, sorry about that misunderstanding.

Comment: And also you are using `plannedweek` in your `check()` function but it is declared in your `setWeek()` function. Please check your console for the errors. You have many errors though.

Comment: @firatozcevahir thanks for that, but its still not working.

Comment: Why is there a lowercase L (`l`) many times in the `d.getMonth()+l==` checks? Typo, or forgot to declare & initialize?

Comment: @firatozcevahir didn't know you cant use variables that aren't in the same function in html. Thank you i added the parameter for plannedweek and d in the check function, but its still broken.

Comment: I see an undefined on setWeek. Are you getting a 404 on your JS included file or is your JS file being included?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Several issues

- Typos (missing `=` on days and elemen)
- Scope (var d is not visible in check), setweek not known to the onload handler
- `l` not defined

Here I use an event handler

```js
var d = new Date();

function setweek() {
  var days = ["Sunday", "Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday", "Saturday", "Sunday", "Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday", "Saturday"]
  var elemen = ["first", "second", "third", "fourth", "fifth", "sixth", "seventh"];
  var day;
  var dayofmonth = 0;

  var month = d.getMonth() +1; // JS months start a 0
  for (var i = 0; i < 7; i++) {
    day = days[d.getDay() + i];
    dayofmonth = d.getDate() + i;
    document.getElementById(elemen[i]).innerHTML = day + '<br>' + dayofmonth + "." + month;
  }
}

window.addEventListener("load", setweek)


// if you need the last day of the month do this

const lastDay = date => new Date(date.getFullYear(),date.getMonth()+1,0).getDate();

console.log(lastDay(d))
```

```html
<section id="meal_plan_section">
  <label for="weekly_meal_plan">Weekly meal plan:</label><br>
  <ul class="list-group" id="weekly_meal_plan">
    <li id="first" class="list-group-item list-group-item-action"></li>
    <li id="second" class="list-group-item list-group-item-action"></li>
    <li id="third" class="list-group-item list-group-item-action"></li>
    <li id="fourth" class="list-group-item list-group-item-action"></li>
    <li id="fifth" class="list-group-item list-group-item-action"></li>
    <li id="sixth" class="list-group-item list-group-item-action"></li>
    <li id="seventh" class="list-group-item list-group-item-action"></li>
  </ul>
  <br>
```

Note: If you need the last day of the month do this

```
const lastDay = date => new Date(date.getFullYear(),date.getMonth()+1,0).getDate();
```

I THINK, you wanted this

```js
const days = ["Sunday", "Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday", "Saturday"]
const elemen = ["first", "second", "third", "fourth", "fifth", "sixth", "seventh"];

function setweek() {
  let d = new Date();
  const start = d.getDate();
  for (let i = 0; i < 7; i++) {
    d.setDate(start + i)
    document.getElementById(elemen[i]).innerHTML = days[d.getDay()] + '<br>' + d.getDate() + "." + (d.getMonth() + 1);
  }
}

window.addEventListener("load", setweek)
```

```html
<section id="meal_plan_section">
  <label for="weekly_meal_plan">Weekly meal plan:</label><br>
  <ul class="list-group" id="weekly_meal_plan">
    <li id="first" class="list-group-item list-group-item-action"></li>
    <li id="second" class="list-group-item list-group-item-action"></li>
    <li id="third" class="list-group-item list-group-item-action"></li>
    <li id="fourth" class="list-group-item list-group-item-action"></li>
    <li id="fifth" class="list-group-item list-group-item-action"></li>
    <li id="sixth" class="list-group-item list-group-item-action"></li>
    <li id="seventh" class="list-group-item list-group-item-action"></li>
  </ul>
  <br>
```

Comment: Thank you. This was the solution for the setweek problem. removing the check(i) has fixed it. Ill have to work on it some more.

Comment: @BottomCroat Please see my SECOND version. I think that is what you actually wanted - a 7 day period from today, changing month when at the end of the month

Comment: @mrplungjan Yeah i wanted it to check for the next 7 days. I just wanted it to be in a function because i want to make another function which will go to the next week. But now i can use the setDate function which you showed me.

Comment: @mrplngjan It seems like a error occurs when I use d.setDate(start+i+(weeknumber*7)) where weeknumber is how many times I clicked a button to add a week, the problem occurs when i pass the month. it starts skipping months it seems.

Comment: I have no idea what you mean. You have  not shown any button in your script and where and what is weeknumber?

Comment: My answer only answers your initial question based on your initial code. If you have new questions. please ask a new question posting relevant code in a snippet

Comment: Ill edit the question so you can see what i mean.

Comment: ah ill ask a new then. sorry about that.